# Add/remove validation rules Dynamically

Tags: jquery, validation

I need to dynamically add validation rules to a text box when the user clicks on the checkbox in that row and remove it when the user unchecks it. This is what I did, and it works fine, but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it.
Here's my html code:

```
<tbody>
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="selectItems" value="<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" />
      </td>
      <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/></td>
      <td align="left"><c:out value="${item.driver.fullName}"/></td>
      <td align="left"><input type="text" name="mileage_<c:out value="${item.numberPlate}"/>" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>                       
</tbody>
```

and my jquery:

**-----EDITED----**

Now I'm using **add/removeClass** and it also works fine,but isn't there a quicker way of doing this? I mean , one way to avoid writing so many 'add/removeClass' instructions? and finally how could I indicate "min:100" or " minlength:6" with addClass?

```
$("input[name=selectItems]").change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
       {  
            $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").addClass('required');
            $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").addClass('number');
       }
     else
       {
            $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").removeClass("required")
            $(this).closest("tr").find("input[name^=mileage]").removeClass('number');

       }
 });
```

[image]

any suggestion is welcome and... I almost forgot, Merry Xmas!

Comment: Keep in mind that client-side (javascript) validations are easily hacked.  Make sure to implement server-side validations, then play with jQ stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small improvement would be to use addClass and removeClass instead of assigning class values using attr so that you would not remove any classes already assigned to the input fields that don't deal with validation (i.e. classes assigned to style the fields)

**Edit:** : (Updated the code below as per your comments)

```
$("input[name=selectItems]").change(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var scoper = me.parent().parent();
        var otherInputs = $("input[name^=mileage]", scoper);
    if (this.checked)
       {  
            otherInputs.addClass('required number');
            otherInputs.attr('maxlength', '6');
       }
     else
       {
            otherInputs.removeClass("required number");
       }
 });
```

Comment: I made what you told me and now I'm using add/removeClass , but I still have some doubts, please check the comment below the ----Edited--- in my question

Comment: thanks a million now the function looks much better, but please tell me how could I indicate "min:100" or " minlength:6" with addClass? this is the last question , I promise :$

Comment: If you want to apply the restriction of size you can use maxLength attribute, for minimum value you have to tweak the validation. I am not sure you can achieve either of them using addClass

Comment: @Cybernate- Could you please, give me a hand over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532009/placing-error-message-for-a-checkbox-array